# Unit Testing and Mocking SubscriberClient (Google Pub/Sub) in a C# Project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm using Google Cloud Pub/Sub (Google.Cloud.PubSub.V1 (2.2.0)) in a .NET Core 3.1 project.
I'm trying to write a unit test for the code that retrieves messages from a Google Pub/Sub subscription.
My code is similar to what you find in the Google documentation.

```
var subscriber = await SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(subscriptionName);

try
{
    var startTask = subscriber.StartAsync(async (PubsubMessage message, CancellationToken cancel) =>
    {
            //code
    });
    
    await Task.Delay(5000);
    await subscriber.StopAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    await startTask;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
        //code
}
```

Is there a way to mock SubscriberClient in a unit test? SubscriberClient doesn't appear to have an interface.
My unit tests are using NUnit (3.12.0) and Moq (4.14.5).

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Calling `SubscriberClient.Create(...)` instead of `.CreateAsync(...)` allows you to pass in the underlying `SubscriberServiceApiClient` instance(s).</s>

*Edit: Apologies, the above is incorrect, it should be:*

Instantiate a `SubscriberClientImpl` directly instead of calling `SubscriberClient.CreateAsync(...)`. This allows you to pass in the underlying `SubscriberServiceApiClient` instance(s).
Note that you can pass `new SubscriberClient.Settings()` for the `settings` argument, and `null` for the `shutdown` argument as defaults.

`SubscriberServiceApiClient` can be mocked - either directly, or by instantiated a `SubscriberServiceApiClientImpl` instance and passing in a mocked `Subscriber.SubscriberClient`.

When testing, note that `SubscriberClient` is multi-threaded and with default settings will call the callback passed to `StartAsync` concurrently from multiple threads.

Comment: Hi Chris. If I change the code from SubscriberClient.CreateAsync() to SubscriberClient.Create(), then I get the error message "Cannot access internal method 'Create' here". Am I missing something?

Comment: Apologies, you are correct, this method is internal. I've corrected the answer.